# Adding AABB Collision in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to set up AABB Collision with the cube I am rendering using DX11.

I have a UserInput class which holds the variables of each cube, such as location, coordinate locations etc.

I've made it so the light cube will only appear when the boxes are colliding which works fine. But for some reason, I'm unable to get them collision to they are unable to pass through each other.

User Input Class

```
class UserInput
{
public:
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    float zPos;
    Vector3 vecMin;
    Vector3 vecMax;
    float rotationX;
    float rotationY;
    float rotationZ;
    bool isMoving;
    bool isMovingRight;
    bool isMovingLeft;
    bool isMovingUp;
    bool isMovingDown;
    bool isMovingCloser;
    bool isMovingFurther;
    bool isRotatingX;
    bool isRotatingY;
    bool isRotatingZ;
    UserInput()
    {
        rotationX = 0.0f;
        rotationY = 0.0f;
        rotationZ = 0.0f;
        isMovingRight = false;
        isMovingLeft = false;
        isMovingUp = false;
        isMovingDown = false;
        isMovingCloser = false;
        isMovingFurther = false;
        isRotatingX = false;
        isRotatingY = false;
        isRotatingZ = false;
    }

    void UpdatePos()
    {
        //-1 and +1 from the origin of the cube (centre)
        vecMin.x = xPos - 1.0f;
        vecMax.x = xPos + 1.0f;
        vecMin.y = yPos - 1.0f;
        vecMax.y = yPos + 1.0f;
        vecMin.z = zPos - 1.0f;
        vecMax.z = zPos + 1.0f;
        vecMin.x = xPos - 1.0f;
        vecMax.x = xPos + 1.0f;
        vecMin.y = yPos - 1.0f;
        vecMax.y = yPos + 1.0f;
        vecMin.z = zPos - 1.0f;
        vecMax.z = zPos + 1.0f;
    }
};
```

Bounding Box Function

```
bool AABBtoAABB(const UserInput& box1, const UserInput& box2)
{
    return(box1.vecMax.x > box2.vecMin.x &&
        box1.vecMin.x < box2.vecMax.x &&
        box1.vecMax.y > box2.vecMin.y &&
        box1.vecMin.y < box2.vecMax.y &&
        box1.vecMax.z > box2.vecMin.z &&
        box1.vecMin.z < box2.vecMax.z);
}
```

Update Function

```
void Update()
{
    AABBtoAABB(input[0], input[1]);
    input[0].UpdatePos();
    input[1].UpdatePos();
}
```

I can't seem to work out how to actually have them hit each other and not pass through each other.

Comment: You completely ignore result of `AABBtoAABB` instead of adjusting positions of those boxes if they intersect.

Comment: See [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) ``DirectXCollision.h``.

Comment: I've looked at them files, and I don't understand what's going on...